# Can not get any return value from webView.geturl, (code shown below)

Tags: java, android, webview

```
public class Browser1Activity extends Activity {

    TextView url;
    WebView ourBrow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvURL);
        // cancel the web intent that default in android setting
        ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // webView seeting
        ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        try {
            ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.au");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        url.setText(ourBrow.getUrl());
    }

}
```

Why I can't get the return value form `webView.geturl`? The setting for the `TextView` is totally fine and the `WebView` worked as well, but when I launch the emulator, the url didn't show anything. Is there anything wrong with the `ourBrow` setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is no problem in your code it was gave you null due to the url is not load at that time when you are trying to set it on Text. you must set the text after load the url on web View to test your code just add a button and onClick of that button do same

```
 url.setText(ourBrow.getUrl());
```

as you did in your code you got the url on text.

Answer (score 0):

in order for your Activity to access the Internet and load web pages in a WebView, you must add the INTERNET permissions to your Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```